# Joomla category thinks it's a blog

Tags: joomla3.0

I've created a new Joomla category named "press-releases" but somehow it thinks it's a blog article. (see image)

Is there a setting to change this to Uncategorized? In other words, how do I disassociate this category from the blog category?

The press-release category has no parent, as shown in the image below.

[image: Associated with blog]

[image: press-release category]

Answer (score 0):

Blog is the menu entry name, which you can change to anything you want in Menu Manager. There is 0 relationship between the name of the menu entry name and the type of content it points to.

Similarly, Timesheet & Project Management Blog is the title of that category, you will want to change that too.

Comment: You may have misunderstood. The title of the category is "Press Releases" but it displays "Timesheet & Project Management Blog" instead. I don't know why.

Comment: As I explained, that is the title of that section as typed in the menu entry.